# Can't get VIdeoView to Shuffle

Tags: android, android-videoview, shuffle

I have a videoview in android that is reading lines from a text file and playing them. The text file contains links to audio and video files on a webserver. However when it reaches the end of the song/video it will not play the next one.

It seems that I need to implement an `OnCompletionListener` but I have no idea how to do that. Would that be the correct path to go down?

I have tried putting it in a loop to perform the play method X amount of times but it just hangs. I am assuming it just keeps shuffling randomly until it reaches the end of the loop.

I have also attempted to get it to pause for the length of the audio/video track by using `videoVIew.getDuration()`

The code is below:

```
try {
         BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new DataInputStream(new FileInputStream(file))));
         LineNumberReader rdr = new LineNumberReader(br);

          int min = 1; //Line 1 (start of file)
          int max = 20; // Line 20 (end of file)
          Random r = new Random();
          int someRandomNo = r.nextInt(max - min + 1) + min; 
          textView1.setText(Integer.toString(someRandomNo));
          // get random number - go to line - save it
          rdr.setLineNumber(someRandomNo);
          int linenum = 0;
          String theLine = "";
          while (linenum < someRandomNo) {
              theLine = br.readLine();
              linenum++;
          }
          textView1.setText(theLine);

              VideoView videoView = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.VideoView);         
              MediaController mediaController = new MediaController(this);
              mediaController.setAnchorView(videoView);
      // Set Audio/Video to play
              Uri video = Uri.parse(theLine);
              videoView.setMediaController(mediaController);
              videoView.setVideoURI(video);
              videoView.start();                                      
      }
      catch (Exception e) {

      }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what you want:

```
viedoView.setOnCompletionListener(MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener l);
```

And the onCompletionListener resource on android dev- http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener.html

And for what its worth, I would suggest you do your IO with the file once, and save theLine in an array or ArrayList and that way you can access it, or even make a custom class to handle shuffling. For example you could have it keep track of which strings had been sent, ie which videos has been played, and then randomly choose a new one that had not been played yet.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, that would make since

Answer (score 0):

AJcodez answer was what I needed, I was just unsure how to use the OnCompletion Listener.

I put my OnCreate code into its own method and then simply had the listener call it everytime. I also wasn't implementing the `MediaPayer.OnCompletition` Listener for the class.

```
//Implement the listener
public class CardioActivity extends Activity implements MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener {

//Oncreate calls play
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);   
        play();
}

 public void play() {
                    //Blah blah all other code is here
                    //Set the listener etc like this
                videoView.setMediaController(mediaController);
                videoView.setVideoURI(video);
                videoView.setOnCompletionListener(this);                    
                videoView.start();              
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
         //Handling exceptions
        }
    }

@Override
public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer arg0) {
    //Recall the method
    play();
}
```

[Another SO link that I came across](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5365323/mediaplayer-oncompletionlistener-and-view-onclicklistener)